# Spring JPA can't pass parameter into quotes

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to do request to PostgreSQL, that looks like this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT t FROM Tasks t WHERE daterange(t.date_from, t.date_to) && daterange '(:dateFrom, :dateTo)'", nativeQuery = true)
Page<Task> findTest(@Param("dateFrom") String dateFrom,
                        @Param("dateTo") String dateFrom,
                        Pageable pageable);
```

in the result values of `dateFrom` and `dateTo` not passing into `:dateFrom` and `:dateTo` because of single quotes.
`:dateFrom` and `:dateTo` looks like a strings. If I remove quotes, parameters passing fine, but request, of course, invalid.
So is it any way to pass values into quoted `(:dateFrom, :dateTo)`?

Comment: In addition to what Sebastion said in the answers, are you sure `daterange` expects strings rather than PostgreSQL's Date/Time types?  JPA has support for turning the various Java `Date`, `Calendar`, and (since JPA 2.2) `java.time` classes into their database equivalents... although you may need a `@Temporal` annotation to specify *which* type of Date/Time to pass.

Comment: You can use between for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is not working without quotes because you're trying to get the data with something like this:

*get tasks* **WHERE** *date > 2015* **AND** *date > 2014*

Basically, if you're trying to get a task from 1st June 2014 it will work fine, but then the `date > 2015` won't be true. 
So I suggest you to change the `&&` into `<@`, in this way, if I've understood your requirement, the task date range is contained by the range built with parameters .

[Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-range.html) are some nice operators for range types.

Comment: Thank you! <@ works fine for me! My final query now looks like that: @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Tasks WHERE daterange(date_from, date_to) <@ daterange(:dateFrom, :dateTo)", nativeQuery = true). But I changed type :dateFrom and :dateTo from String to java.sql.Date